# GPS tracking system

Tags: c#

I recently am working on a GPS software for my dad company. Every truck driver has a laptop in their computer and I am trying to make a software to locate where they go. from a previous post I saw here, there was a guy who suggested this [GPS SYSTEM LINK(codePlex)](http://gps.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/24953#development/MainForm.resx)

An unhandled exception of type "System.IO.IOException' occurred in System.dll

Additional information: The port 'COM1' does not exist."

this is the button code 
. `

```
private void connectButton_Click (object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            _port.Open();
            _timer.Start();
        connectButton.Enabled = false;
        disconnectButton.Enabled = true;
        portList.Enabled = false;
    }
```

and this is the entire code of the form [Link of the code](http://gps.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/24953#development/MainForm.cs)

`

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.IO.Ports;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace GPS
{
    public partial class MainForm : Form
    {
        private GgaCommand _lastGga;
        private GsaCommand _lastGsa;
        private GsvCommand _lastGsv;
        private RmcCommand _lastRmc;
        private GllCommand _lastGll;
    public MainForm ()
    {
        Control.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = false;

        InitializeComponent();

        _port.NewLine = "\r\n";
    }

    protected override void OnLoad (EventArgs e)
    {
        portList.Items.AddRange(System.IO.Ports.SerialPort.GetPortNames());
        portList.SelectedIndex = portList.Items.Count - 1;

        base.OnLoad(e);
    }

    public Satellite[] Satellites
    {
        get
        {
            if (_lastGsv == null)
                return new Satellite[0];

            List<Satellite> sats = new List<Satellite>(_lastGsv.Satellites);

            for (int i = 0; i < sats.Count; i++)
                sats[i] = sats[i] + _lastGsa;

            return sats.ToArray();
        }
    }

    private void portList_SelectedIndexChanged (object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _port.PortName = portList.SelectedItem as string;
    }

    private void connectButton_Click (object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _port.Open();
        _timer.Start();

        connectButton.Enabled = false;
        disconnectButton.Enabled = true;
        portList.Enabled = false;
    }

    private void disconnectButton_Click (object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _timer.Stop();
        _port.Close();

        connectButton.Enabled = true;
        disconnectButton.Enabled = false;
        portList.Enabled = true;
    }

    private void timer_Tick (object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try {
            string data = _port.ReadLine();

            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(data) == false) {
                ProcessCommand(data);
            }
        } catch (Exception exc) {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(exc);
        }
    }

    private void altitude_CheckedChanged (object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RefreshAltitude();
    }

    private void distance_CheckedChanged (object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RefreshDistance();
    }

    private void ProcessCommand (string data)
    {
        // all commands start with dollar signs
        if (data[0] != '$')
            return;

        //System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(data, "Command");

        if (data.IndexOf('*') != -1)
            data = data.Substring(0, data.IndexOf('*'));

        switch (data.Substring(3, 3)) {

            case "GGA":
                _lastGga = new GgaCommand(data);
                latitudeValueLabel.Text = _lastGga.Location.Latitude.ToString("N6");
                longitudeValueLabel.Text = _lastGga.Location.Longitude.ToString("N6");
                RefreshAltitude();
                break;

            case "GSA":
                _lastGsa = new GsaCommand(data);
                RefreshSattellites();
                break;

            case "GSV":
                _lastGsv = _lastGsv + new GsvCommand(data);
                RefreshSattellites();
                break;

            case "RMC":
                _lastRmc = new RmcCommand(data);
                directionImage.Invalidate();
                bearingValueLabel.Text = _lastRmc.DirectionalAngleInDegrees.ToString();
                RefreshDistance();
                break;

            case "GLL":
                _lastGll = new GllCommand(data);
                break;

            default:
                System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine("*** " + data.Substring(3, 3) + " Not Handled", "Command");
                break;
        }
    }

    private void RefreshAltitude ()
    {
        float altitude = _lastGga.Location.AltitudeInFeet;

        if (altitudeInMetersRadio.Checked)
            altitude = _lastGga.Location.AltitudeInMeters;

        altitudeValueLabel.Text = altitude.ToString();
    }

    private void RefreshDistance ()
    {
        float speed = _lastRmc.Knots;

        if (milesPerHourRadio.Checked)
            speed = _lastRmc.MilesPerHour;
        else if (kilometersPerHourRadio.Checked)
            speed = _lastRmc.KilometersPerHour;

        speedLabel.Text = speed.ToString("N2");
    }

    private void RefreshSattellites ()
    {
        Satellite[] satellites = this.Satellites;

        for (int i = 0; i < satellites.Length; i++) {
            Satellite sat = satellites[i];
            ListViewItem item = sat.Tag as ListViewItem;

            if (item == null) {
                item = new ListViewItem(new string[] {
                        sat.Prn.ToString(),
                        sat.SignalQuality.ToString()
                    },
                    satelliteList.Groups[sat.HasFix ? "hasFixGroup" : "doesNotHaveFixGroup"]
                );

                satelliteList.Items.Add(item);
            }

            sat.Tag = item;
        }

        satilliteLocationImage.Invalidate();
    }

    private void satilliteLocationImage_Paint (object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        float centerXF = (float)satilliteLocationImage.Bounds.Width / 2F;
        int centerX = satilliteLocationImage.Bounds.Width / 2;
        float centerYF = (float)satilliteLocationImage.Bounds.Height / 2F;
        int centerY = satilliteLocationImage.Bounds.Height / 2;
        float maxRadius = (Math.Min((float)satilliteLocationImage.Bounds.Height, (float)satilliteLocationImage.Bounds.Width) - 20F) / 2F;

        using (Pen circlePen = new Pen(Color.DarkBlue, 1)) {

            double[] elevations = new double[] { 0, Math.PI / 2, Math.PI / 3, Math.PI / 6 };

            foreach (double elevation in elevations) {
                float radius = Convert.ToSingle(System.Math.Cos(elevation) * maxRadius);
                e.Graphics.DrawEllipse(circlePen, (centerXF - radius), (centerYF - radius), (2F * radius), (2F * radius));
            }

            e.Graphics.DrawLine(circlePen, new Point(centerX - 4, centerY), new Point(centerX + 4, centerY));
            e.Graphics.DrawLine(circlePen, new Point(centerX, centerY - 4), new Point(centerX, centerY + 4));
        }

        if (_lastGsv == null)
            return;

        Satellite[] satellites = this.Satellites;

        if (satellites != null && satellites.Length > 0) {

            using (Pen satellitePen = new Pen(Color.Yellow, 4F)) {
                using (Pen hasFixSatellitePen = new Pen(Color.Green, 4F)) {

                    foreach (Satellite sat in satellites) {
                        double h = (double)System.Math.Cos((sat.Elevation * Math.PI) / 180D) * maxRadius;

                        float satX = centerXF + Convert.ToSingle(h * Math.Sin(((float)sat.Azimuth * Math.PI) / 180D));
                        float satY = centerYF - Convert.ToSingle(h * Math.Cos(((float)sat.Azimuth * Math.PI) / 180D));

                        e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(sat.HasFix ? hasFixSatellitePen : satellitePen, satX, satY, 4F, 4F);
                        e.Graphics.DrawString(sat.Prn.ToString(), new Font("Tahoma", 8, FontStyle.Regular), new System.Drawing.SolidBrush(Color.Black), new PointF(satX + 5F, satY + 5F));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void directionImage_Paint (object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        int centerX = directionImage.Bounds.Width / 2;
        int centerY = directionImage.Bounds.Height / 2;
        float maxWidth = Math.Min((float)directionImage.Bounds.Height, (float)directionImage.Bounds.Width) - 40F;
        float centerXF = (float)directionImage.Bounds.Width / 2F;
        float centerYF = (float)directionImage.Bounds.Height / 2F;
        float radius = maxWidth / 2F;

        e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Black, new Point(0, centerY), new Point(directionImage.Bounds.Width, centerY));
        e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Black, new Point(centerX, 0), new Point(centerX, directionImage.Bounds.Height));
        e.Graphics.DrawEllipse(Pens.Black, centerXF - (maxWidth / 2F), centerYF - (maxWidth / 2F), maxWidth, maxWidth);

        using (Font directionFont = new Font("Tahoma", 12F, FontStyle.Bold)) {
            e.Graphics.DrawString("N", directionFont, Brushes.Purple, centerXF, 0F);
            e.Graphics.DrawString("S", directionFont, Brushes.Purple, centerXF, directionImage.Bounds.Height - 20);
            e.Graphics.DrawString("E", directionFont, Brushes.Purple, directionImage.Bounds.Width - 20, centerYF);
            e.Graphics.DrawString("W", directionFont, Brushes.Purple, 0, centerYF);
        }

        using (Pen anglePen = new Pen(Color.Blue, 4F)) {
            e.Graphics.DrawLine(anglePen, new PointF(centerX, centerY), new PointF((radius * Convert.ToSingle(Math.Cos(_lastRmc.DirectionalAngleInRadians))) + centerXF, (radius * Convert.ToSingle(Math.Sin(_lastRmc.DirectionalAngleInRadians))) + centerYF));
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: There is no COM1 in your PC? You might want to check if you have any: http://superuser.com/questions/835848/how-to-view-serial-com-ports-but-not-through-device-manager and if not, buy some.

Comment: Is GPS device plugged in ? Edit : You can expose USB device port as COM1, but it's not really recommended.

Comment: @ Vytautas Plečkaitis , was hopping to get it by using the same system as microsoft or google or other softwares use to locate your PC. for example "Prey Project" detects your exact location if you are connected to the internet. The laptops will be connected to the internet so, was hopping to do something like that.

Comment: @rene can u please explain better what you mean?

Comment: The code (and project) are meant mostly to connect directly to GPS device and get data from it. Easiest way for you though - use [Google geolocation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-geolocation) api.

Comment: I can't explain it any better then: You don't have a COM1 connected in/to your PC. There is nothing wrong with your code (so far), you have a local issue that we can't help with because we can't buy or install or configure external devices for you. It is similar as if you would try to go to say drive K:\, you'll probably get the same IO Exception (as I assume you don't have a drive K:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compiled and tried on GPS device. GPS SYSTEM LINK (on [codePlex](http://gps.codeplex.com/)) basically connects to gps reciever, get's response (based on [NMEA](http://www.gpsinformation.org/dale/nmea.htm) standards) from device (e.g. `$GPGSV,2,1,08,01,40,083,46,02,17,308,41,12,07,344,39,14,22,228,45*75`), splits it to values and displays in appropriate labels. And that's it. This code kind of works (was abandoned in 2007), but it won't let you do what you want - e.g. real time multi user tracking.

In my opinion easiest way for you would be [google geolocation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geolocation/intro) integrated with [google maps](https://developers.google.com/maps/) - there are plenty examples of that.

Comment: Yea, I've been working with google geolocation ever since, looks like there are many tools of offline libraries which can do the job done to.